# Meta Length Logarithms

Tags: code-golf, math

Good Evening Golfers,

Your challenge, this evening, is logarithmic, and (as Abed would put it) "Meta"

Your goal is to write a program that takes an input from stdin or the command line, and returns the logarithm of that number, in the base of the length of your program in bytes.

So, if your program is 10 bytes, it must return the Log10 of the input number.

Rules:

- Program must be longer then 1 character
- Program must be able to accept floating point input in a form of your choice, or scientific format in a form of your choice with a minimum accuracy of 6 digits
- Program must output to a minimum of 6 digits of accuracy in decimal or scientific format
- Program must be entirely self contained, and must not access any files or network resources.

Your score in the natural logarithm of the amount of bytes in your source code.

Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

### APL 1.0986122886681098

```
3⍟⎕
```

⎕ Requests numerical screen input. Examples of use:

```
      3⍟⎕
      10
2.0959032742893844

      3⍟⎕
      1E1
2.0959032742893844

      3⍟⎕
      ○1
1.041978045992186
```

In the last example ○1 represents pi.

Comment: I count 7 *bytes* in your program so the score should be `1.9459101490553132`.

Comment: @Bakuriu. I am sorry if you are counting unicode bytes. I have explained this situation so many times now. APL+WIN uses a single byte character set but the only way I can get the characters to render properly on this site I have to convert the characters to UTF-8. The byte count for my solution is a genuine 3!

Comment: Then you should declare the encoding you use to let other people check. Probably the OP should have decided a canonical encoding to avoid ambiguous results, and if I were him I'd definitely choose utf-8.

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica: 2.079.. (length in bytes = 8)

```
8~Log~#&
```

Usage

```
8~Log~# &@8
(*
 1
*)
```

Answer (score 6):

## bc (with -l) - log(15) = 2.70805

```
l(read())/l(15)
```

Answer (score 5):

## Q (log(16) = 2.772589)

```
16 xlog"F"$(0:)0
```

Example

```
q)16 xlog"F"$(0:)0
16
1f

q)16 xlog"F"$(0:)0
1.6e1
1f

q)16 xlog"F"$(0:)0
13.912231123
0.9495705
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby: 2.995732273553991 (`Math.log 20`)

```ruby
p Math.log$_.to_f,20
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ ruby -ne 'p Math.log$_.to_f,20' <<< 3.14
0.3819509540359265
```

Answer (score 4):

### J, 2.4849066497880003102297094798389 (12 chars)

```
12^.".1!:1[1
```

Usage:

```
   12^.".1!:1[1
12
1
```

Answer (score 3):

## Perl: 2.77258872223978 (`log 16`)

```perl
say log()/log 16
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.2$ perl -nE 'say log()/log 16' <<< 3.14
0.412691139779226
```

Comment: `$_=log()/log 15` with option `-pe` instead of `-nE`.

Answer (score 3):

### Tcl, 3.4011973816621555 (log 30)

```
puts [expr log($argv)/log(30)]
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), ln(2) = 0.6931471805

```
Zl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PwqILQA)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), score: [0.693147...](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4ivbz//40A) (2 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage))

```
.²
```

05AB1E has a 2-byte \$\log_2{n}\$ builtin. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f79Cm//8NDQA) or [verify the inputs in the range [0,3] in increments of 0.1](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kenhuiH5Zpb2SwqO2SQpK9pX/9Q5t@q/zHwA).

Otherwise it would have been 3 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) instead:

```
3.n
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fWC/v/39DAwA) or [verify the inputs in the range [0,3] in increments of 0.1](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9kenhuiH5Zpb2SwqO2SQpK9pX/jfXy/uv8BwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.²  # Get the logarithm in base 2 of the (implicit) input
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)

3   # Push 3
 .n # Pop and get the logarithm in base 3 of the (implicit) input
    # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python (`log 38`) score: `3.6375861597263857` <- how embarrassing

```
>>> import math;print math.log(input(),38)
38**8
8.0
```

Answer (score 2):

## Lua 3.5835189384561 (36 <strike>38 42</strike> chars)

```
L=math.log;print(L(io.read())/L(36))
```

Sample run:

```
C:...>echo 42 | lua -e "L=math.log;print(L(io.read'*n')/L(36))"  
1.0430165662508
C:...>echo 38 | lua -e "L=math.log;print(L(io.read'*n')/L(36))"  
1.0150877453695
C:...>echo 36 | lua -e "L=math.log;print(L(io.read'*n')/L(36))"  
1
C:...>
```

Comment: Do you really need to force the input into a number? For numeric input works anyway and for non-numeric input crashes anyway. (Beside that, handling input error was not required in the question.) You can spare 2 characters by using `()` instead of `'*n'`: http://pastebin.com/461tUsse

Comment: Hmm, apparently the '*n' isn't needed. Lua generally avoids automatic type coercions, but there are a few cases where strings do get converted to numbers. The team keeps threatening to remove them and a lot of Lua users just assume type coercions don't happen as a safety measure. So, this brings us down to 36 chars, as soon as I make the edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Smalltalk** (Pharo 2.0) **(41 ln) 3.713572066704308**

```
Pharo -headless Pharo-2.0.image eval "FileStream stdin nextLine asNumber log:41"
```

No syntactic sugar is Smalltalk's pride, just regular sentence ;)

Answer (score 2):

## Scala - ln(46) = 3.82864...

`print(math.log(args(0).toDouble)/math.log(46))`

`scala log.scala 12.34` -> 0.6563283834264416

Answer (score 1):

## CJam - ln(5) = 1.60943791243

```
rd5mL
```

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript 69 bytes, score=4.23410650459726**

```
function f(n){return Math.log(n)/Math.log(69);}
```

I counted bytes following this discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219526/how-many-bytes-in-a-javascript-string

```
function byteCount(s) {          
        return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
    }
```

The number of characters is only 37.
Any advice on counting bytes in code golf?

Comment: If you put your source code in a file, the file size will be the number of bytes

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 1.38629436112

```
.lQ4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy8n0OT/f1MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), score \$\ln(2)=0.693147...\$

```
ļƥ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yJ5jS///NwIA)

```
ļ       implicit input; log base 2
 ƥ      prints the top of the stack
```